# jQuery convert all images to anchor

Tags: jquery, image, replace, anchor

I want to convert all images like this:

```
<img src='example.com/img1.jpg' />
<img src='example.com/img2.jpg' />
<img src='example.com/img3.jpg' />
```

to:

```
<a href='example.com/img1.jpg' rel='shadowbox[Mixed]'><img src='example.com/img1.jpg' /></a>
<a href='example.com/img2.jpg' rel='shadowbox[Mixed]'><img src='example.com/img1.jpg' /></a>
<a href='example.com/img3.jpg' rel='shadowbox[Mixed]'><img src='example.com/img1.jpg' /></a>
```

with jQuery, I tried this:

```
$("img").replaceWith( "<a rel='shadowbox[Mixed]' href='"+$(this).attr("src")+"'><img src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'/></a>" );
```

but not worked :(

Comment: What doesn't work? When you check the browser inspector, does it show any change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`wrap`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$("img").wrap(function(){
    return "<a rel='shadowbox[Mixed]' href='"+$(this).attr("src")+"'></a>";
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/84nc3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function(k,v) {
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).prop('src') + '" rel="shadowbox[Mixed]" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (however, you would probably want to use @Musa's .wrap() solution which is much more elegant):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('img').each(function() {
         var attr = $(this).attr('src');
         var newElement = "<a href='" + attr + "' rel='shadowbox[Mixed]'><img src='" + attr + "' /></a>"

         $(newElement).insertAfter($(this));
         $(this).remove();

    });     

});
```

**DEMO jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9DUGH/1/

**A useful read:** [.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)